# Azure Databricks SQL download query results

Tags: databricks

I'm fairly new to Databricks. I have an SQL query in a notebook and I want to download the full results (about 3000 rows) to a CSV file. However, when I run the query, it takes half an hour to display the first 1000 rows (which is useless to me) and then I have to click on "Download full results" which re-runs the query, hence the half hour it had just spent was completely wasted.

Is there a way to download the full results without first displaying the first 1000 rows in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might be this will help -
Create 1 variable and Load your table into the variable
Mytable = spark.table("tableName")

then storing the data into the csv file with option like
Mytable.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", "as per your requirement").option("header", "true").save("dbfs:/df/mytabledata.csv")

then you can download/access the file under the data bricks instance file system.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be go to a notebook instead of sql editor, write the query u need, it will display u top 1000 records, click on the arrow of result and choose download all rows (up to 5Gb compressed) option, a csv will be download with all rows